# SQL timestamp on Update read in Java

Tags: java, sql, client, timestamp, database-server

I am writing a Client Server Application now when the Client sends a command to the Server the Record in the SQL Database is updated and On Update a Timestamp is set on a field. But now I want to read all the Users in the SQL Database that where online in the last hour with the Timestamp.

So this is how far I am:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE lastonline...
```

lastonline is the field with the timestamp of the users last update. I now have no Idea how to check if he was online in the last hour.

I thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select username FROM user WHERE lastoinline>"date now - 1 hour" AND lastoinline<="date now"

```
Date dеNow = new Date();
Date веBefore = tdNow; tdBefore.setHours(tdBefore.getHours()-1);
String query = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE lastonline>='"+(dtBefore.getTime/1000)+"' AND lastonline<='"+(dtNow.getTime/1000)+"'
```

"

Answer (score 0):

Compare the current hour with the hour on the timestamp's record.

If you are using sql server:

`SELECT DATEPART(hh, GETDATE())` --current hour

`SELECT DATEOART(hh, ColumnStoredInDB)` --stored hour

**Spoiler:** Simply take the ColumnStoredInDB from the current hour and if the difference is < 1 that user has been in the system for the last hour.  If the difference >=1 you can skip that record

Comment: Is `DATEPART` function generic SQL function or is it RDBMS specific?

Comment: You didnt tag your question with the RDBMS, I was assuming SQL Server, if not Oracle and other vendors have something similiar.  So please consult the documentation based on what you are using...

Comment: Sorry for net mentioning I am using MySQL

Comment: mysql has an hour function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

Comment: I didn't create this question. I was just asking because there is no tag of the specific RDBMS that the OP used.